# Can I apply for Poland's visa appointment from different country if I'm different country citizen?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, applications, poland

I need your help here

I m Indian Citizen and i want to apply for national visa for my collage , but the problem is i m not getting any dates in India , So can i apply for appointment from Malaysia because i have Malaysia tourist visa still valid for me ,

So please tell me can i book appointment in Malaysia because i can see dates available in Malaysia , So can i book them and go for the interview in Malaysia <

does it matter that where i m apply from ? its just an visa interview Right ?

i m sharing you link where i can my application screen shot for you

prnt.sc/ob4761
prnt.sc/ob47q6

Answer (score 1):

Highly unlikely.

Schengen rules state that only applications from persons who reside legally in the jurisdiction of the competent consulate should be accepted.
However, an application may be accepted from a person legally present – but not residing - in the jurisdiction of the consulate where the application is submitted, if he can justify why the application could not be lodged at a consulate in his place of residence. It is for the consulate to appreciate whether the justification presented by the applicant is acceptable.

‘I couldn’t get an appointment at a Consulate in my place of residence’ probably won’t be accepted as reasonable justification.

https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#page23